# Getting the sum of records returned from a model in Laravel 4.1

Tags: controller, laravel-4, view, models

I have the following in my user module

```
// A user has many assets.
public function assets()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('Asset');
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
$assetValue = User::find($id)->assets;
```

I only want to sum up the values from a single field from the records returned and pass it to a view.

I've tried using all sorts of SUM() calls and I am now stumped.

So something like this would be great

```
$assetValue = User::find($id)->assets->sum('values');
```

Thanks

Edit* The output of $assetValue = User::find($id)->assets;

```
[{"id":"1","name":"asset1","serial_num":"1234","value":"100.00","created_at":"2014-03-18 20:06:37","updated_at":"2014-03-18 20:06:37","pivot":{"user_id":"1","asset_id":"1"}},

{"id":"2","name":"asset2","serial_num":"5678","value":"200.00","created_at":"2014-03-18 20:06:37","updated_at":"2014-03-18 20:06:37","pivot":{"user_id":"1","asset_id":"2"}},

{"id":"3","name":"asset3","serial_num":"91011","value":"300.00","created_at":"2014-03-18 20:06:37","updated_at":"2014-03-18 20:06:37","pivot":{"user_id":"1","asset_id":"3"}}]
```

Comment: Using `sum` like you have should technically work. What is the result of that and are you using the right column name?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the right column name (value). I printed out $assetValue and added the output to my question. 

The result of using:
`$assetValue = User::find($id)->assets->sum('value');` is
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User::find($id)->assets` will give you a `Eloquent\Collection` which doesn't allow you to query the results as they've already been pulled from the database.

To access the `Eloquent\Builder` object which would allow you to query the results you need to use `User::find($id)->assets()->sum('value');`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this when I'm home and mark as answer when it works :)